# Google Drive API Custom Role for Folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I've recently been attempting to create folders in Google Drive with the Google Drive API. I've successfully created all the nested files and shared them through the addition of permissions but have been unsuccessful in altering the capabilities of the folder.

I'd ideally like to have users able to upload files to the folder, but have no ability to rename, change the description or delete the folder. I attempted to reassign the folder capabilities as shown below:
(Personal Folder is just a var for the specific file being worked on)

```
PersonalFolder.capabilities = Drive.newFileCapabilities();
PersonalFolder.capabilities.canEdit = false;
PersonalFolder.capabilities.canDelete = false;
PersonalFolder.capabilities.canRename = false;
PersonalFolder.capabilities.canShare = false;
```

However, despite the capabilities saving and reporting the correct settings on Logger, upon sharing the folder it reverts to the default capabilities of the role assigned (writer, commenter, etc).

Is there any way to force the change or to edit the capabilities of the role directly?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: you cannot change any roles, but can only assign roles to users. in this case it may be defined by the requested API scope... voted to close this question, because the provided sample code lacks the request for the scope, therefore it lacks relevant parts.  https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles ...hint: for buckets one can define `ACL`, as you may require it.

Comment: Your code here sets the local script folder metadata. Did you `patch` this data back to Drive? If not, then you never actually set anything in the actual online resource. Unlike `DriveApp`, the REST API does not do any communication except for the `Drive.<noun>.<verb>(params)` lines.